# Movie where a girl fought her inner demons of conformity on the way to the bathroom

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a part of this movie. It was an artistic movie, it looked like it shouldn't have been a movie, but it was. There was a girl, the protagonist, dressed in a green long dress, assisting a gala with her family. She pretended she liked the play that they were watching from a very fancy round table, and she smiled when people watched her, trying to please everyone in her family.

However, she excused herself to go to the bathroom. On the way to the bathroom, she started making weird faces, and dancing frantically, fighting the demons that made her conform to society. She found a tall black man, who she attacked artistically and dismayed him. She was looking at the camera most of the time while she was dancing, and she could shoot projectiles out of her hands, like small lightning bolts.

EDIT: Since the original video was shut down, I re-created it. I hope you enjoy it (and I also hope they don't copyright strike me...

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBDJb4-eeYA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: "it looked like it shouldn't have been a movie, but it was" - in what way shouldn't have been? "attacked artistically and dismayed him" - what does this mean?

Comment: I felt like it shouldn't have been a movie, because the actress was staring into the camera the while she was dancing the whole time. Also, when he attacked the man, it looked like they were acting as if they were inside a theatre play: she grabbed him by the face, and while he was talking on the phone, he dropped his phone and looked at her exaggerating his fear; then, he fell to the ground very robotically, to the rythm of the music playing while she was dancing prior to the attack.

Comment: It sounds more like an early 90's music video

Comment: The video where I watched it was very neat, it looked like an HD camera, so probably it was made after 2007

Comment: sound like "Sucker Punch" for me except she don't go to gala

Comment: Where did you see this movie? At a theatre, on television (what channel? time of day?), streaming (what provider?), online (what sites do you watch things on?), etc? When did you see this? How much of it did you see? What language was spoken, if any? What race was the protagonist and/or her family? What was the play they were watching? How many people were there? How did you know the demons she was fighting were demons of conformity? What were some of the other demons like? What else can you tell us?

Comment: @AlexM i saw it on a bar at night. Don’t know the channel or anything. I saw it a year ago and the part I saw was about 3 minutes long. I was hypnotized, but couldn’t stay longer. No language was spoken, because the people’s voices were superposed with some kind of alternative music. Woman and her whole family were white caucasian. She had brown straight hair, fixed backwards for the occasion. She was tall and thin, about 5’9’’ with the black heels she was wearing and about 90 pounds. Her eyes were painted black and she had a powerful gaze. The gala had about 15 to 30 people applauding

Comment: @AlexM part2: the demons were not present in the scene, it was figurative speech; someone edited the title too literally

Comment: So we don't actually know that it was a movie - could be movie, TV show, actual music video as suggested previously, or other...

Comment: @AlexM you are right, however since it was more than 3 minutes long, a music video would be too weird. It looked like it was a movie or some artistic production, however due to the weirdness in the video I thought I'd give it a try in this SE site

Comment: FWIW, gaining the power to emit energy blasts from your hand due to the power of music seems SF enough to me.

Comment: In case that's a controversial position, I started a Meta post at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/are-possibly-metaphorical-fantastic-elements-valid-to-make-a-work-fantasy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a weird coincidence, I only saw that for the first time during the week. It was linked from an online conversation about the music video for Fatboy Slim's "Weapon of Choice", due to the similarities.

It's by the same director (Spike Jonze) and isn't a movie but actually a perfume ad for Kenzo World. It was made in 2016.

Comment: I love you. This is why I love the Internet.